# How to add JWT auth to swagger (go + echo + swaggo/swag)

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-2.0, go-echo

I am using swaggo (https://github.com/swaggo/swag) to auto-create a working swagger specification for my API.

The swagger spec allows me to run all of my API endpoints and receive responses.

I then added JWT authentication to all of my endpoints.  Now I'm unable to use the swagger spec to run any endpoints, as it always fails auth.

What annotations do I need to add to each endpoint, that will configure the Swagger spec to allow a JWT to be passed?

I've read the README at https://github.com/swaggo/swag and Google searched, to no avail.

Answer (score 8):

You will need these in main.go (this will send token in format to your header: "`YourTokenName`: `token`") :

```
//@securityDefinitions.apikey <YourTypeOfKey>
//@in header
//@name <YourTokenName>
```

Then add this comment to every endpoint that need an auth token:

```
// @Security <YourTypeOfKey>
```

Comment: what if i have both X-Api-Key and JWT? @vũ-nam-hà

Answer (score 6):

Seems that these comments added to each endpoint did the trick...

```
// @Security ApiKeyAuth
// @param Authorization header string true "Authorization"
```

This comment was also added to our main.go file

```
// @securityDefinitions.apikey ApiKeyAuth
```

Comment: isnt adding a //@param defeating the purpose of the annotation in main.go file?
I mean adding it as a @param is like saying, hey I need this as a header for this endpoint explicitly

Answer (score 1):

`// @Param Authorization header string true "Insert your access token" default(Bearer <Add access token here>)`

Add this param to header for each endpoint in swagger v2.0

In V3.0, we have direct bearer token access.